# How can I get the EDM type from 'context' bound to an element in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have an SAPUI5 application.

I defined an element by the smart fields like the following:

```xml
<smartField:SmartField value="{GefahrInVerzug}" width="auto">
    <smartField:configuration>
        <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false" displayBehaviour="descriptionOnly"/>
    </smartField:configuration>
</smartField:SmartField>
```

The `GefahrInVerzug` field is defined as a boolean in my metadata:

```xml
<Property Name="GefahrInVerzug" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:creatable="true" 
sap:updatable="true" sap:deletable="true" sap:label="Gefahr in Verzug"/>
```

Assume I have the following handler for `onInputChange` event of the rendered control:

```js
onInputChange: function (oEvent) {
    var oField = oEvent.getSource(),
    oContext = oField.getBindingContext();
    //oContext.getEdmType();
}
```

How can I get the `Edm Type` by accessing the element (i.e. `oField`) or the context object (i.e. `oContext`).

In this case I am looking for a solution that return `Edm.Boolean` to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define the following functions in our controller to extract `Edm Type` from a field:

```js
 // Returns a list that contains a map between 
 // UI5 elements' types and the property that contains the value!
 // Normally bound to the oData property 
 _getFieldTypeAttribute: function () {
    var aFieldTypes = {
        "sap.m.Input": "value",
        "sap.m.Select": "selectedKey",
        "sap.m.ComboBox": "selectedKey",
        "sap.m.CheckBox": "selected",
        "sap.m.DatePicker": "dateValue",
        "sap.m.DateTimePicker": "value",
        "sap.m.TextArea": "value",
        "sap.m.Switch": "state",
        "sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField": "value"
    };
    return aFieldTypes;
},

// Extract the EDM type from Metadata
_getEdmType: function(oField, sPropertyName){
    var regex = /\/([^(]+)/gm,
    oContext = oField.getBindingContext(),
    oModel = oContext.getModel(),
    oMetaModel = oModel.getMetaModel(),
    sBindingPath = oContext.getPath(),
    sType = null;
    //
    var aMatches = regex.exec(sBindingPath);
    if(aMatches.length > 0){
        var sSetName = aMatches[1],
            oEntitySet = oMetaModel.getODataEntitySet(sSetName),
            sEntityType = oEntitySet.entityType,
            oEntityType = oMetaModel.getODataEntityType(sEntityType),
            oProperty = oMetaModel.getODataProperty(oEntityType, sPropertyName);
            if (oProperty ) {
                sType = oProperty.type;
            }
    }
    //
    return sType;
},

// Is fied when the input value is changed!
onInputChange: function (oEvent) {
    var oField = oEvent.getSource(),
        oContext = oField.getBindingContext(),
        oModel = oContext.getModel(),
        aFieldTypes = this._getFieldTypeAttribute(),
        sFieldType = oField.getMetadata().getName(),
        sFieldPath = oField.getBinding(aFieldTypes[sFieldType]).getPath(),
        sPropertyName = sFieldPath && sFieldPath.startsWith("/") ? sFieldPath.substring(1) : sFieldPath,
        sBindingPath = sPropertyName ? oContext.getPath() + "/" + sPropertyName : null; 
    console.log(this._getEdmType(oField, sPropertyName));
}
```

It prints `Edm.Boolean` for example when this function is fired for an element of boolean type!

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look here](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/13/metadata-binding-in-ui5/)

```
onInputChange: function (oEvent) {
    var oField = oEvent.getSource(),
    oContext = oField.getBindingContext(),
    sType = oContext.getProperty("/#EntityName/GefahrInVerzug/@type");
}
```

> In metadata MaxLength , Type are in capital letters but in that name
> you can’t get the metadata values.

Comment: This is also a good solution when we have separated 'InputChange' methods for each input. However, normally I have one general function for all the inputs.